# Azure Web App local network communication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, architecture

I'm designing a micro service architecture hosted in Azure that will have the following .NET applications:

- Azure Web App - MVC application
- Azure web App - Web API application
- Azure Web APp - Web API application

The MVC application will be the only one accessible through a web browser.
When a user clicks a button, the MVC application will call one or both Web APIs (using REST calls).

Right now the Web APIs are accessed through their external urls (the ones hosted under .azurewebsite.net). The problem with this is that the traffic goes through the internet.

Is there a way for the MVC Application to call the Web APIs through a sort of "local network" so that there won't be delays due to the traffic going through the internet?

Thanks

PS:
If this can't be achieved by using Azure Web Apps, can it be achieved with Azure Cloud Service? I know it can be achieved with IaaS, but I wouldn't want to take that route as it would require me to take care of all the IT stuff.

Comment: Tale a look at app service environments

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be what I need. Not too excited by it being available only in Premium tier :)

Comment: From your question, if I understand you correctly you want the MVC app call the API app internally and block inbound request from the internet to your other apps apart from the MVC app? The answer is Virtual network ( VNET). With VNET and subnet, you can create a range of private IPs for your apps to communicate without exposing it to the internet. The link between gives an overview of how to achieve it.  

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/

I hope this helps!